# Transition effects for sticky header with fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header that takes the "sticky" class on window scrolling by JS, the header dimensions differ on sticky because some elements are displayed on the original header and hidden on the sticky header, but it's the same element that is displayed.

I have been trying to make the transition smooth and nice, so I wanted to add some (*Fade-in*) and (*Fade-out*) transition, I was able to add the fade-in by adding the transition effect to background-color, such as:

```
 transition: background-color 800ms linear;
```

But it's not the case for the fade-out, as I want the sticky header styling to disappear smoothly while the original header (which is the same element) should display instead, so whatever I tried was hiding the header at all on fade-out, all questions and searching on Google I found that they all have the same header dimensions and just reduce the opacity, or they have two header elements, the original header and one that takes the sticky styling and just hide the sticky one using:

```
$(header).fadeOut(800);
```

In my case, which is the same element I want to hide, but I need to make it smooth, what can I do?

HTML:

```
<div class="main">

  <div class="header">
    Test Header
    <div class="showOnSticky">
      <p>
        Stricky Header
      </p>
      <p>
        Stricky Header
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="dontShowOnSticky">
      <p>Don't display me on sticky header</p>
      <p>
        Test
      </p>
      <p>
        Test
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contents">
    Test some other elements

    <div>
some content .....
</div> 

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.header {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  transition: background-color 2s linear;
}

.header.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 2s linear;
}

.header.sticky .dontShowOnSticky {
  display: none;
}

.header.sticky + div {
  padding-top: 310px;
}

.contents {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;

}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var header = document.querySelector(".main .header");
  var header_scroll_top = header.offsetTop + header.clientHeight;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if (header) {
      var window_scroll_top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      if (window_scroll_top > header_scroll_top && !header.classList.contains("sticky")) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      } else if (window_scroll_top < header_scroll_top && header.classList.contains("sticky")) {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a demo for my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/k3g2y9z7/

Comment: Can you give us an example? A website or something?

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW Well, the jsfiddle I posted is pretty much simulating the site I am working on, please check: https://jsfiddle.net/k3g2y9z7/

Comment: I mean a website in which there's a menu like you want...

Comment: Check this https://www.tandfonline.com/toc/ytex20/current , this site is using a separate element for the sticky header, I am doing the same thing but for the same element

Comment: @Paulie_D Edited, please check.

Comment: Are you just looking for a menu where the navigation fades in on scrolling and fades out on scrolling?

Comment: @Xp10d3 yes, I am looking for the fade-out effect on scrolling up in the window